# Vagrant messes up code?

Tags: virtual-machine, vagrant, virtualbox, puppet

With the following [Git repo](https://github.com/calebdre/Portable-Vagrant), when I execute `vagrant up`, the machine boots up correctly and everything show up exactly how it should. When I start editing code, however, Vagrant totally mangles the code.

When the page is pulled up, sometimes the last 10 lines of the document is missing and sometimes there are random non-unicode characters that cause errors. When I ssh into the virtual machine and look at the code, it's the exact same as what's in my editor. Nothing is being cached.

I've tried re-provisioning, editing the Vagrantfile, destroying the boxes (even in Virtualbox) and bringing it back up, and uninstalling and reinstalling vagrant all to no avail.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: What's running in your VM? Is it also mangled when you SSH in and request HTML via `nc` or `curl`?

Comment: Can you give the Vagrantfile you're using?What code is being mangled?

Comment: @FelixFrank this is the vagrant config i'm using: [on github](https://github.com/calebdre/Portable-Vagrant)

Comment: @PeterSouter it's javascript codeon the browser. On the server and local everything is fine, however when viewed in the browser code is missing or it doesn't show up correctly

Comment: Here is what appears: https://www.dropbox.com/s/t7difuzxp4m6xz6/Screenshot%202014-09-06%2017.28.41.png?dl=0

Comment: Are you using the regular version or the 'laravel' version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been struggling with what I assume to be the same problem. Judging by the repo nginx is being used.

In nginx.conf set sendfile to off. This worked for me.

See here for more information:
https://coderwall.com/p/ztskha/vagrant-apache-nginx-serving-outdated-static-files-turn-off-sendfile